# Reduce time needed for SIFT Brute-force Matcher Algorithm in OpenCV

Tags: performance, algorithm, opencv, sift

I've been wondering how can SIFT Brute-force Matcher (for object identfication) time be reduced. My program iterates over some trainsets of images and returns the maximum number of matches found in each case. Is there a way (except for resizing the images to a smaller scale) to shorten this time interval because I think that the greater becomes my database it will be rendered useless if I have a huge identification time?

Thanks in advance

PS I use Python Bindings for OpenCV 2.4.9

Comment: if the bruteforce algorithm is perfectly optimized, the only way to reduce the computation time is to redduce the number of features ;). Other methods would be not to use brute-force matcher but some other methods, like ´Locality Sensitive Hashing´ , space partitioning or clustering

Comment: Thank you! I think that I should also wrap some C++ code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you try flann matcher...... thats much faster than bruteforce......

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#py-feature-homography

Comment: I have wrapped some C++ code using FLANN matcher with SIFT